# RibbonWindow.Hide() and Window.ShowDialog() problems on .net 4.5

Tags: wpf, .net-4.5

I changed the .net Version of my WPF Application from .net 4.0 to 4.5 and replaced the old ribbonlibrary with the new one (System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon).

After that I noticed some strange behaviour on the following case (which works fine before):

The Main Window is a RibbonWindow.
A RibbonButton executes a Command with this simplified code:

```
App.Current.MainWindow.Hide();
new Window().ShowDialog();
```

When the modal Dialog shows up the CPU goes mad:
[image: CPU goes mad]

If I remove the Hide() line, it works fine.

Am I missing a change on the ribbon controls library for .net 4.5 or do I using it wrong?